# Shortcut Ctrl+Shift+B doesn't work in MyEclipse Java Enterprise perspective

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

I created a Java Project in MyEclipse, and then I opened its Java source file with MyEclipse Java Enterprise perspective instead of Java perspective. Then I found <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> doesn't work, but the shortcut still work when I switch to Java perspective.

I wonder why it doesn't work in MyEclipse Java Enterprise perspective.
Thank you:-).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed in the latest MyEclipse 2015 CI 14 release.